# Push a array into a GLOBALS variable?

Tags: php, arrays, global-variables, array-push

after debugging about 2-4hrs I found out, that `array_push(...)` cannot push variables into global scopes... The content of the GLOBALS variable only exists in the function where I pushed the array into the GLOBALS variable...

The content of the pushed GLOBALS variable doesn't exists in the next function... I do not why php is working like that, but anyway. I need a way to push a array into a GLOBALS array to work with the content of this GLOBALS array in the next function.

So, I need some solutions. Does anybody knows, how I can solve that?

Greetings and Thank You!

Comment: You could try sessions instead.

Comment: Post example code demonstrating this issue.

Comment: Do you have a link or example?

Comment: The `$GLOBALS` variable exists in all functions. But if you really need to access global variables, I think it's better to use the `global` statement to declare them.

Comment: It exists, yes. But it is empty... what is the globale statement?

Comment: It works fine for me: http://ideone.com/2pslVQ

Comment: @FrazeJr. http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php scroll down to **The *global* keyword**

Comment: @Barmar look at the picture in this post. There you see, it is not working for me... and also, I declared it as GLOBALS: http://stackoverflow.com/q/43415021/7691812

Comment: I don't see where you're calling the functions. Are you calling all the functions in the same script invocation, or are they different invocations of the script? Variables aren't kept between invocations, except for session variables.

Comment: I have no idea what `add_action()` does. I guess it's something related to WordPress or some other framework you're using?

Comment: Yeah, as I described in the question. The functions are additional code for a plugin!

Comment: @FrazeJr. Always, always add supporting information to your question itself via an edit.  Forcing readers to comb through a long list of comments and click on a bunch of hyperlinks is not good practice.  Please insert all relevant commented info into your question and delete your comments so that you don't waste anyone else's time and your question is easy to understand and answer.